# useDapp activateBrowserWallet not working

Tags: javascript

The error argument for activateBrowserWallet was removed
`activateBrowserWallet(errorHandler)`

Now when a user connects their wallet, how are errors dealt with?

[The docs are out of date](https://usedapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html), and don't actually reflect the current changes.

For example..

```
const config: Config = {
  networks: [Fantom]
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <DAppProvider config={config}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </DAppProvider>
  )
}
```

When users connect their wallet on a non-Fantom chain (Avalanche for example).. no error is thrown.

```
try {
      await activateBrowserWallet();
    } catch (e) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
```

Before the error argument was removed, this error was caught. Now it is not.